# Divide int into 2 other int

Tags: objective-c, xcode, variables, int

I need to divide one int into 2 other int's. the first int is not constant so one problem would be, what to do with odd numbers because I only want whole numbers. For example, if int = 5, then int(2) will = 2 and int(3) will = 3. Any help will greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. `n-1` and `1` will always add to `n` and fit the bill as you've explained it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try ceil and floor functions from math to produce results like 2 and 3 for odd inputs;

```
  int(2)=ceil(int/2); //will produce 3 for input 5
  int(3)=floor(int/2); //will produce 2 for input 5
```

Comment: I would suggest casting the arguments of ceil to doubles or floats since integer division truncates...  So it would be `int(2) = ceil((float)int / 2.0f);`

Answer (score 4):

Supposing you want to express `x = a + b`, where `a` and `b` are as close to `x/2` as possible:

```
a = ceiling(x / 2.0);
b = floor(x / 2.0);
```

That's pseudo code, you have to find out the actual functions for floor and ceiling from your library. Make sure the division is performed as floating point numbers.

As pure integers:

```
a = x / 2 + (x % 2 == 0 ? 0 : 1);
b = x / 2
```

(This may be a bit fishy for negative numbers, because it'll depend on the behaviour of division and modulo for negative numbers.)

Answer (score 0):

Well my answer is not in Objective-C but i guess you could translate this easily.
My idea is:

```
part1 = source_number div 2
part2 = source_number div 2 + (source_number mod 2)
```

This way the second number will be bigger if the starting number is an odd number.